# Solution to given Integral equation

Tags: integration, problem-solving

I want to determine the solution $f(x)$ of the integral equation
\begin{equation}
    f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}(x-y) f(y) d y+x^{2} .
\end{equation}
I got
$$
f(x)=x^2+ \int_{0}^{1}xf(y) d y-\int_{0}^{1}f(y)y d y
$$
so
$$
f(x)=x^2+ax+b
$$
with
$$
\begin{aligned}
&a=\int_{0}^{1}f(y) d y\\
&b=-\int_{0}^{1}-yf(y) d y.
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, we plug in $x^2+ax+b$ in the equation and get
$$
\begin{aligned}
&a=\int_{0}^{1}(y^2+ay+b) d y\\
&b=\int_{0}^{1}y(y^2+ay+b) d y.
\end{aligned}
$$
which equals
$$
\begin{aligned}
&a=\dfrac{6b+3a+2}{6}\\
&b=\dfrac{6b+4a+3}{12}
\end{aligned}
$$
and this gives
$$
a= \frac{3}{13}
$$
and
$$
b=- \frac{17}{78}
$$
Many thanks to your help.

Comment: Building on the answer from Kavi, you should find $f(x)=x^2+\frac{3}{13}x-\frac{17}{78}$.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot plug in $y$ for $x$ since $y$ is a variable of integration.

Hint for solution: Separating the two terms on the right side we see that $f(x)$ has the form $x^{2}+ax+b$. [ $a=\int_0^{1} f(y)dy, b=\int_0^{1} yf(y)dy$].

Now plug in $f(x)=x^{2}+ax+b$ into the given equation and compare the coefficients of $x$ as well as the constant terms. You get two equations for $a$ and $b$. Solve these two equations.